# ZF2 project not working on virtual host

Tags: apache, zend-framework2, php-5.5

I have a project which is in zf2.
It runs properly on all other systems other than mine.I have checked the virtual host is running properly for other projects on my system.
when I hit `xyx.loc` it redirects properly but when I hit `xyz.loc/user` it gives error

> An error occurred
>
> An error occurred during execution; please try again
>   later.

Though I have enable error reporting.
I am not able to figure out whether its apache error or php error or zf2 error  or something else.
The project uses `ZF\Apigility`
The same folder works on other systems very well.

Comment: When you say that error reporting did not reveal what the error is, what do you mean exactly? Error logs are empty or you can't find them?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have checked apache error logs, it does not show anything meanigful.

Comment: How about PHP logs? I suppose that ZF has its own logs.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can you tell me where they are located. I am new to ZF2.

Comment: just checked the access log found this msg there =>" internal dummy connection"......does this help

Comment: Error messages always help, that's why they are there. I suggest you edit the question and add that information. Don't forget to copy the complete error message as-is (including file and line number information and stack trace if provided) rather than describing it with your own words. (Please note I know nothing about that precise framework, I'm just trying to make the question answerable by those who do.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the [default error template message](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml). ZF2 is catching any exceptions and hiding them from you due to the configuration settings.

Ensure you have the following configuration.

```
'view_manager' => [
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true, 
],
```